# How to connect dynamically created objects with Interface Builder object instances in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, object, iboutlet

I use an IBOutlet to refer between objects created in Interface Builder, BUT...

I need to connect an object pointer (or sth) declared in an NSOperation (MyOperation) subclass with my application Controller (with an IBOutlet?) to invoke some methods of AppController. Is there any way to connect (or bind) them ?

What is the best practice to refer to AppController or any other instance created in Interface builder (added as objects) from other objects that are not created on IB too (lets say dynamically created in runtime) ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Objects created in IB are binded to a property/class, which can be directly accessed by dynamically created views/objects. If by AppController you mean the application delegate, you can access it from anywhere with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]

Comment: by AppController I mean a class (AppController:NSObject) that I add to interface builder to connect (with IBOutlets) other UI objects (NSTextField, etc), then I use this class to refer to UI objects when I need to.

Comment: My question refers to this: I have an NSOperation subclass called MyOperation. I need this class to have an IBOutlet to be connected with AppController described above (in order to invoke some methods or sth in AppController). But is this possible since MyOperation objects are created dynamically during runtime? I mean it's not applicable to add MyOperation in IB to connect any IBOutlets. (Currently I have a delegate property in MyOperation and I set it to AppController (`[myOperation setDelegate self]; [myOperation start]`) before invoking -start. I just ask if there is any other way).Thanks

Comment: You said "If by AppController you mean the application delegate, you can access it from anywhere with [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]" Exactly that but with not application delegate! Assume an other instance in IB, how can I access it from a dynamically created object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to have something that does have an IBOutlet to your object either push pointers to that object into things that are dynamically created, or provide a method for other objects to get that reference.

IBOutlet doesn't make sense in the context of something that is created dynamically, and thus doesn't exist in your nib.